# how to get all fonts using jquery?

Tags: jquery, fonts

Can you please tell me how to get all fonts using jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All Fonts installed on the users PC? Not possible reliably (JavaScript doesn't have that level of access), even though there is a hackish way to check for the presence of a specific font: http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect

Answer (score 1):

This code shall help you much, but only for IE

```
<SCRIPT>
    function getFonts()
    {
        var nFontLen = dlgHelper.fonts.count;
        var rgFonts = new Array();
        for ( var i = 1; i < nFontLen + 1; i++ )
            rgFonts[i] = dlgHelper.fonts(i); 

        rgFonts.sort();
        for ( var j = 0; j < nFontLen; j++ )
            document.write( rgFonts[j] + "<BR>" );
    }
</SCRIPT>

<BODY onload="getFonts()">
<OBJECT id=dlgHelper CLASSID="clsid:3050f819-98b5-11cf-bb82-00aa00bdce0b" width="0px" height="0px">
</OBJECT>
```